# Creating a classic asp function to remove all characteres but number letters and dot comma ;

Tags: excel, asp-classic, oracle11g

How can I create a Classic ASP function to remove all characters coming from pasting excel columns and keep only LETTERS (A..Z), numbers (0..9) and dot comma (;)?

I need the `;` to know where to split the variables... but some cases comes from excel special tabular character and I don't know what the space between the `;` so I need to remove all others except letters numbers and `;` .

```
123456  ;   newVendor
987654321   ;   vendor2
```

I found the function below on oracle, but how can I make it to accept the dot comma ;

```
auxTexto:=trim(TRANSLATE(regexp_replace(upper(texto),'[[:punct:]]','') , '.ÁÀÃÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÕÔÖÚÙÛÜÇ_ ','.AAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC_'));
return auxTexto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
' Assume the string you want to operate on is called inString.
' We will create a string called outString that contains only letters, numbers, and semicolon

dim acceptableCharacters
acceptableCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789;"

dim outString
for i = 1 to Len(inString)
    if InStr(acceptableCharacters, Mid(inString, i, 1)) > 0 then
        outString = outString & Mid(inString, i, 1)
    end if
next
```

This isn't horribly efficient and there are lots of ways to test if the value at position i in inString is in the set of acceptable letters, but this is one way of doing it. Also, it doesn't take into account that there are letters other than A-Z and a-z, such as é and ά, depending on the language and character set we're talking about. But it gives you an idea of how to do something like this in VB/ASP.